# How to use preexisting histogram data to make clustered histogram in Excel

Tags: excel

I have generated histogram data in Mathematica for multiple different series of data. I have the start and end points for the bins, as well as the bin heights. I want to use this preexisting data to create a clustered histogram plot in excel (i.e. within one bin width there would be three different bars representing the data from three different series). How can I do this? Do I have to use the histogram plot, or the bar chart?

Using latest version of excel 365.

I have tried plotting as a bar chart but both the bin data and the height data are plotted as separate series. I cannot get the horizontal axis to display like a histogram. Plotting as a histogram doesn't see to work as it appears to need to original data to create a histogram from; however I need the data to become a weighted histogram which I believe excel cannot do.